# Ionic3 Facebook login issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, facebook-login

Currently i am facing a problem regarding facebook login in my ionic 3 app. As soon as i click login button my app crashes.

I have tried the guide provided in ionic framework docs also followed a youtube video but could not resolve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: You should provide the error that you have experienced.

Comment: When i click the button the app crashes with unfortunately the app has stopped working, but the build is successful

Comment: Hello @Saad I am facing the same issue. How did you resolved it ?